# No internet connection when connected via wi-fi, but fine via ethernet (DD-WRT)

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, dhcp, dd-wrt

I just bought a new router (Linksys WRT160Nv3) and installed DD-WRT on it.

When I connect my Mac to the router via Wi-Fi, I cannot get an outside internet connection (and in fact, can not connect to the router admin interface at 192.168.1.1).

If I connect to it with an ethernet cable, I can get an outside connection just fine. At first that wasn't the case, but I cloned the MAC address of my old router [as suggested here](https://superuser.com/a/456563/5878), and now get an outside connection.

I've tried to duplicate the settings from my old router (Linksys WRT54GS) as best I can (it was also running DD-WRT), but to no avail. What steps can I take to troubleshoot and solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried it with all wireless security disabled ?

Comment: What IP address do you receive when connecting wirelessly?

Comment: What router model.. what dd-wrt version..? sounds to me your Wi-fi  card doesn't associate correctly with the router.. You did mention you replaced an old router with same settings, I'd try to clear the router name from saved wi-fi list on your PC then reconnect again.

Comment: It sounds like you connected your WAN to a LAN port.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck! I have DD-WRT on my router. I'll give you some options to change and see if it fixes things.

1. Go to Wireless > Basic Settings , and check the Advanced Settings box. Try enabling AP Isolation or setting Network Mode to Unabridged.
2. Make sure your wireless card is compatible with 802.11 B,G, or N.
3. Go to Administration > Management , and make sure 802.1x is turned on.

If possible, tell me the IP you get when joining wirelessly, and joining via ethernet. To get that on a mac, enter `ifconfig` in Terminal, and look for IPv4 address.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check you have received the IP from the DHCP pool.
2. Ensure the wireless NIC MAC is not blocked in the router for any reason.
3. Login to the admin interface (in wired) and verify the WLAN settings.
4. Make sure the authenticate / encryption are selected appropriate.

Comment: How do I check that I have received the IP from the DHCP pool. How do I check that the wireless NIC MAC is not blocked in the router?

Comment: 1) To check the IP in command window => ipconfig (MS) or ifconfig (linux)     

2) You need to login to the router using ur wired interface and check the WLAN settings. There might be something stopping ur connectivity.

Comment: What should I be looking for when I run `ifconfig`?

I'm sure there is something blocking my wireless connectivity, but I can't figure out what, which is why I asked the question here.

Comment: you'll be looking to see what IP address the command returns for your wireless interface.